# boxing unboxing, cglib, spring and NoSuchMethodError mystery

Tags: java, spring, boxing, cglib

I use Spring and GWt in my project. In few cases I've got a `NoSuchMethodError` thrown by CGLIB when I invoke a method of a spring bean proxy.

If I look at the error, It shows me that it tries to find a method with `Integer` object instead basic `int` fields.

For example, I've got a method which is defined like that in my spring bean

```
public void saveObject(int value)
{
// some stuff
}
```

When I call this method an error is thrown : `NoSuchMethodError` which indicates it tries to find method `saveObject` with a field `java.lang.Integer` and not a basic `int` field (with I key)

What's the problem ? is there boxing/unboxing problems ? I precise that I call this method with a basic int and not an Integer.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but what version of Java are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using cglib-nodep? That has worked for me in the past. Also check the version of cglib that you are using and try to use the latest one.

Comment: I use the last version of cglib-dep (2.2)